# documentclass uebungsblatt Fehler in Mac texlive \@remblank has an extra }

Tags: packages

Who can help me?
I get an error if I translate

```
\documentclass{uebungsblatt}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

The error message:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/uebungsblatt/ uebungsblatt.cls:184:
Argument of \@remblank has en extra }
```

Thanks for help
Rudi

Comment: Welcome, you might get better results with a highly customizable package for exam sheets called `exsheets`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think exsheets works correctly. Also some small problems remain, i.e. I can't use the headings=block-subtitle successfully. If this also works I could give some comments (points...).

Comment: Your installation might be a bit outated, i don't know. Best to ask a new question, the author of the package is here as well.

Answer (score 5):

The class expects that the file name contains a number. Rename your tex-document e.g. to blatt01.tex.

I also suggest a bug report. 
I would use this class only with great care. It contains lines like `\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}` and the class and the underlying packages are old -- the last changes are from 2006.

Comment: Indeed, otherwise the `\extractnumber` macro on line 184 of `uebungsblatt.cls` fails since `\jobname{}` contains no number.